# What's the correct order of writing for a MSc. and a Dipl.-Ing. degree? (e.g. on a business card)

Tags: masters, degree, titles

I finished my (german) Dipl.-Ing. (FH) degree after 4 1/2 years of studying. After that I started to work and studied parallel via a correspondence course. I'll now shortly (hopefully ;-) ) have the additional title of a MSc. That took me 2 1/2 years but only in part time, so the amount of time I invested was much less, than that for my Diploma.

So in order to reflect the increase in qualification I'd put the degrees like that:

> **Dipl.-Ing. (FH), MSc.** Firstname Lastname

But as the Master is sometimes regarded as a higher form of qualification than the Diploma, it might be correct like this:

> **MSc., Dipl.-Ing. (FH)** Firstname Lastname

**What's the correct order?**

---

edit: 
Like it was pointed out the MSc. is written after the name. So the choice is between:

> **Dipl.-Ing. (FH)** Firstname Lastname, **MSc.**
>
> **Dipl.-Ing. (FH)** Firstname Lastname
>
> Firstname Lastname, **MSc.**

Comment: As others noted, MSc. is usually written after the name. The main issue to find out is if it is allowed to use both at the same time. If both are from different fields, this is perhaps not a problem. It might also differ from one Bundesland to the other. But I am not a lawyer, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: For most cases the answer "MSc is written behind the name" solves the problem of writing order. There are still cases though where this doesn't resolve it like e.g. a common business card layout where the titles are in a separate line (and usually in smaller print) than the name. In this case one has to decide about the order or just put one title on the card like it was suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should notice that in Germany academic titles such as *Dr., Dipl.Ing, Mag* are writen in front of the name, whereas titles such as *M.Sc., B.Sc., M.A., etc.*, a written behind the name (see [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademischer_Grad)). So if it all I would say the correct order is

> **Dipl.Ing (FH)** Firstname Lastname, **M. Sc.**

However, I would just ignore the *Dipl.Ing (FH)*.

Comment: Good point. You're right (of course) the MSc.'s proper place is behind the name so the question of order doesn't arise at all. Leaving away the Dipl.-Ing. would be quite hard for me as it was a lot of work to achieve. (Lots more than the MSc.) But the other alternative of having one title at the front and one at the back looks kinda weird to my eyes. But I guess that's my problem now to decide. ;-) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think the situation is different in people getting the degree after the Bologna process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-nominal_letters than those who had the degree before the Bologna process.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there are not strict rules for this (speaking about Germany). There are few ways to deal with this:

- do not use titles at all except for documents like your CV. Why to list them anyway, isn't it just vanity issue at play here?
- if you want to use titles still (well, it's Germany, right?) list only the highest title you achieved as if it superseded all the lower-grade ones. In the case you have several on the same level, choose one. Should be good enough to get all the respect you are after (since you decided to use titles)
- if you should list the titles of different academic levels, then list them in the order of importance/level: [honorary titles] [prof equivalents] [dr. equivalents] [MSc. equivalents] [BSc. equivalents] [whatever else] Name [whatever comes after the name]

  - well, now it comes to my mind, that how the ordering "after the name" should look like is even more confusing.
- if you live in Austria, list everything you want and need in any arbitrary order (half-joke, of course)

For references check also [here](http://www.bmwf.gv.at/startseite/studierende/academic_mobility/enic_naric_austria/faq/fuehrung_akademischer_grade/), or [here](http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080204062132AAZnURQ), or [here](http://www.haktulln.ac.at/ifom/sites/default/files/OeNORM-Aenderungen_Textdesign.pdf) (part Anrede).

Comment: Using no titles at all might be the solution for E-Mail footers etc.. For our business cards: Our company wants us to put achieved titles there. Also I sometimes find the degrees quite a useful source of informetion about the background a person has (e.g. engineering or business) and what kind of background knowledge I can therefore expect. For example I wouldn't explain IT-Basics if it says Dipl.-Inf. (diploma in computer science) in the E-Mail Footer.

Comment: @Karin: re: the point about business cards and background checking - fair enough, of course I understand, since I lived in DE.